# How Can I Make This Python Script Work With Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I downloaded this script to help me convert some PNGs. It is however, from 2003 and the first time I tried to run it, it gave me errors for exception syntax. I managed to fix that and ran it again. Then it gave me errors for the print syntax. I fixed those as well. Now I have absolutely no idea whats going on besides the script not working.

The script is:

```
from struct import *
from zlib import *
import stat
import sys
import os

def getNormalizedPNG(filename):
    pngheader = "\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n"

    file = open(filename, "rb")
    oldPNG = file.read()
    file.close()

    if oldPNG[:8] != pngheader:
        return None

    newPNG = oldPNG[:8]

    chunkPos = len(newPNG)

    # For each chunk in the PNG file    
    while chunkPos < len(oldPNG):

        # Reading chunk
        chunkLength = oldPNG[chunkPos:chunkPos+4]
        chunkLength = unpack(">L", chunkLength)[0]
        chunkType = oldPNG[chunkPos+4 : chunkPos+8]
        chunkData = oldPNG[chunkPos+8:chunkPos+8+chunkLength]
        chunkCRC = oldPNG[chunkPos+chunkLength+8:chunkPos+chunkLength+12]
        chunkCRC = unpack(">L", chunkCRC)[0]
        chunkPos += chunkLength + 12

        # Parsing the header chunk
        if chunkType == "IHDR":
            width = unpack(">L", chunkData[0:4])[0]
            height = unpack(">L", chunkData[4:8])[0]

        # Parsing the image chunk
        if chunkType == "IDAT":
            try:
                # Uncompressing the image chunk
                bufSize = width * height * 4 + height
                chunkData = decompress( chunkData, -8, bufSize)

            except Exception as e:
                # The PNG image is normalized
                return None

            # Swapping red & blue bytes for each pixel
            newdata = ""
            for y in xrange(height):
                i = len(newdata)
                newdata += chunkData[i]
                for x in xrange(width):
                    i = len(newdata)
                newdata += chunkData[i+2]
                    newdata += chunkData[i+1]
                    newdata += chunkData[i+0]
                    newdata += chunkData[i+3]

            # Compressing the image chunk
            chunkData = newdata
            chunkData = compress( chunkData )
            chunkLength = len( chunkData )
            chunkCRC = crc32(chunkType)
            chunkCRC = crc32(chunkData, chunkCRC)
            chunkCRC = (chunkCRC + 0x100000000) % 0x100000000

        # Removing CgBI chunk        
        if chunkType != "CgBI":
            newPNG += pack(">L", chunkLength)
            newPNG += chunkType
            if chunkLength > 0:
                newPNG += chunkData
            newPNG += pack(">L", chunkCRC)

        # Stopping the PNG file parsing
        if chunkType == "IEND":
            break

    return newPNG

def updatePNG(filename):
    data = getNormalizedPNG(filename)
    if data != None:
        file = open(filename, "wb")
        file.write(data)
        file.close()
        return True
    return data

def getFiles(base):
    global _dirs
    global _pngs
    if base == ".":
        _dirs = []
        _pngs = []

    if base in _dirs:
        return

    files = os.listdir(base)
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(base, file)
        try:
            st = os.lstat(filepath)
        except os.error:
            continue

        if stat.S_ISDIR(st.st_mode):
            if not filepath in _dirs:
                getFiles(filepath)
                _dirs.append( filepath )

        elif file[-4:].lower() == ".png":
            if not filepath in _pngs:
                _pngs.append( filepath )

    if base == ".":
        return _dirs, _pngs

print ("iPhone PNG Images Normalizer v1.0")
print (" ")
print ("[+] Searching PNG files..."),
dirs, pngs = getFiles(".")
print ("ok")

if len(pngs) == 0:
    print (" ")
    print ("[!] Alert: There are no PNG files found. Move this python file to the folder that contains the PNG files to normalize.")
    exit()

print (" ")
print (" -  %d PNG files were found at this folder (and subfolders).") % len(pngs)
print (" ")
while True:
    normalize = raw_input("[?] Do you want to normalize all images (Y/N)? ").lower()
    if len(normalize) > 0 and (normalize[0] == "y" or normalize[0] == "n"):
        break

normalized = 0
if normalize[0] == "y":
    for ipng in xrange(len(pngs)):
        perc = (float(ipng) / len(pngs)) * 100.0
        print ("%.2f%% %s") % (perc, pngs[ipng])
        if updatePNG(pngs[ipng]):
            normalized += 1
print (" ")
print ("[+] %d PNG files were normalized.") % normalized
```

Now when I run it in the DOS window, I get this error:

```
C:\wamp\www\py>ipin.py
iPhone PNG Images Normalizer v1.0

[+] Searching PNG files...
ok

 -  %d PNG files were found at this folder (and subfolders).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\wamp\www\py\ipin.py", line 158, in <module>
    print (" -  %d PNG files were found at this folder (and subfolders).") % len(pngs)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

What do I do?

Comment: Have you tried running [2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) on it? You could also install version 2.7 of python, which is what most people use anyways.

Comment: Is it possible to get some documented statistics of how many people use each version of Python?

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Not to the best of my knowledge, no, I am speaking merely from anecdotal evidence, in that I've never actually met someone who uses Python 3, and seemingly very few questions on here seem to use Python 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to move the `%` operator inside the parenthesis.

```
print (" -  %d PNG files were found at this folder (and subfolders)." % len(pngs))
```

Comment: Now I get these erros:
`$ ipin.py
./ipin.py: line 25: from: command not found
./ipin.py: line 26: from: command not found
./ipin.py: line 27: import: command not found
./ipin.py: line 28: import: command not found
./ipin.py: line 29: import: command not found
./ipin.py: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./ipin.py: line 31: `   def getNormalizedPNG(filename):''

Comment: Sorry, I really don't use markdown much :/ 
Anyway, using 2to3, I got this error: /bin/env: python: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, plain string literals are bytestrings, while in Python 3 they are Unicode strings. If you want to write a bytestring literal, use the `b` prefix, e.g. b"\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n". Python 3 is strict when it comes to mixing bytestrings with Unicode strings.

Other differences are that in Python 3, `print` is now a normal function, not a statement, the `range` function returns a generator, like `xrange` in Python 2, and that `input` is like `raw_input` in Python 2 (there's no equivalent of Python 2's `input` function in Python 3 - it was dropped because it was deemed unsafe).

Here's my attempt to translate the code into Python 3 (incidentally, using `from something import *` is discouraged because it could inadvertently hide many names; import only those names you wish to use):

```
from struct import *
from zlib import *
import stat
import sys
import os

def getNormalizedPNG(filename):
    pngheader = b"\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n"

    file = open(filename, "rb")
    oldPNG = file.read()
    file.close()

    if oldPNG[:8] != pngheader:
        return None

    newPNG = oldPNG[:8]

    chunkPos = len(newPNG)

    # For each chunk in the PNG file    
    while chunkPos < len(oldPNG):

        # Reading chunk
        chunkLength = oldPNG[chunkPos:chunkPos+4]
        chunkLength = unpack(">L", chunkLength)[0]
        chunkType = oldPNG[chunkPos+4 : chunkPos+8]
        chunkData = oldPNG[chunkPos+8:chunkPos+8+chunkLength]
        chunkCRC = oldPNG[chunkPos+chunkLength+8:chunkPos+chunkLength+12]
        chunkCRC = unpack(">L", chunkCRC)[0]
        chunkPos += chunkLength + 12

        # Parsing the header chunk
        if chunkType == b"IHDR":
            width = unpack(">L", chunkData[0:4])[0]
            height = unpack(">L", chunkData[4:8])[0]

        # Parsing the image chunk
        if chunkType == b"IDAT":
            try:
                # Uncompressing the image chunk
                bufSize = width * height * 4 + height
                chunkData = decompress( chunkData, -8, bufSize)

            except Exception as e:
                # The PNG image is normalized
                return None

            # Swapping red & blue bytes for each pixel
            newdata = b""
            for y in range(height):
                i = len(newdata)
                newdata += chunkData[i]
                for x in range(width):
                    i = len(newdata)
                    newdata += chunkData[i+2]
                    newdata += chunkData[i+1]
                    newdata += chunkData[i+0]
                    newdata += chunkData[i+3]

            # Compressing the image chunk
            chunkData = newdata
            chunkData = compress( chunkData )
            chunkLength = len( chunkData )
            chunkCRC = crc32(chunkType)
            chunkCRC = crc32(chunkData, chunkCRC)
            chunkCRC = (chunkCRC + 0x100000000) % 0x100000000

        # Removing CgBI chunk        
        if chunkType != b"CgBI":
            newPNG += pack(">L", chunkLength)
            newPNG += chunkType
            if chunkLength > 0:
                newPNG += chunkData
            newPNG += pack(">L", chunkCRC)

        # Stopping the PNG file parsing
        if chunkType == b"IEND":
            break

    return newPNG

def updatePNG(filename):
    data = getNormalizedPNG(filename)
    if data != None:
        file = open(filename, "wb")
        file.write(data)
        file.close()
        return True
    return data

def getFiles(base):
    global _dirs
    global _pngs
    if base == ".":
        _dirs = []
        _pngs = []

    if base in _dirs:
        return

    files = os.listdir(base)
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(base, file)
        try:
            st = os.lstat(filepath)
        except os.error:
            continue

        if stat.S_ISDIR(st.st_mode):
            if not filepath in _dirs:
                getFiles(filepath)
                _dirs.append( filepath )

        elif file[-4:].lower() == ".png":
            if not filepath in _pngs:
                _pngs.append( filepath )

    if base == ".":
        return _dirs, _pngs

print ("iPhone PNG Images Normalizer v1.0")
print (" ")
print ("[+] Searching PNG files..."),
dirs, pngs = getFiles(".")
print ("ok")

if len(pngs) == 0:
    print (" ")
    print ("[!] Alert: There are no PNG files found. Move this python file to the folder that contains the PNG files to normalize.")
    exit()

print (" ")
print (" -  %d PNG files were found at this folder (and subfolders)." % len(pngs))
print (" ")
while True:
    normalize = input("[?] Do you want to normalize all images (Y/N)? ").lower()
    if len(normalize) > 0 and (normalize[0] == "y" or normalize[0] == "n"):
        break

normalized = 0
if normalize[0] == "y":
    for ipng in range(len(pngs)):
        perc = (float(ipng) / len(pngs)) * 100.0
        print ("%.2f%% %s" % (perc, pngs[ipng]))
        if updatePNG(pngs[ipng]):
            normalized += 1
print (" ")
print ("[+] %d PNG files were normalized." % normalized)
```

Comment: I get this:

$ ipin_py.py
./ipin_py.py: line 1: from: command not found
./ipin_py.py: line 2: from: command not found
./ipin_py.py: line 3: import: command not found
./ipin_py.py: line 4: import: command not found
./ipin_py.py: line 5: import: command not found
./ipin_py.py: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./ipin_py.py: line 7: `def getNormalizedPNG(filename):'

Comment: What's that `$`? Are you still running it on Windows? I ask because it looks to me like it's not recognising it as a Python script. That could occur if you're running it on Linux without the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/python` (details of shebang may vary).

Answer (score -1):

What happens when you try % str(len(pngs))?

Comment: This isn't an answer (and clearly is not intended as one); please remove it.