# Migrate script in python 2 to python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, png

Following this past question: [How Can I Make This Python Script Work With Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872790/how-can-i-make-this-python-script-work-with-python-3)

I would like to make this script work in python 3.
I've managed to fix some details but it still doesn't work.. now it seems throwing a error when decompressing the chunk data.

Here is the current error I have: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream

I'm using Python 3.6.2

And here is the script with things already migrated to Python 3.
The script basically normalizes a PNG with custom iphone format.

```
import pdb
from struct import *
from zlib import *
import stat
import sys
import os
import zlib

def getNormalizedPNG(filename):
    pngheader = b"\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n"

    pdb.set_trace()

    file = open(filename, "rb")
    oldPNG = file.read()
    file.close()

    if oldPNG[:8] != pngheader:
        return None

    newPNG = oldPNG[:8]

    chunkPos = len(newPNG)

    # For each chunk in the PNG file
    while chunkPos < len(oldPNG):

        # Reading chunk
        chunkLength = oldPNG[chunkPos:chunkPos+4]
        chunkLength = unpack(">L", chunkLength)[0]
        chunkType = oldPNG[chunkPos+4 : chunkPos+8]
        chunkData = oldPNG[chunkPos+8:chunkPos+8+chunkLength]
        chunkCRC = oldPNG[chunkPos+chunkLength+8:chunkPos+chunkLength+12]
        chunkCRC = unpack(">L", chunkCRC)[0]
        chunkPos += chunkLength + 12

        # Parsing the header chunk
        if chunkType == b"IHDR":
            width = unpack(">L", chunkData[0:4])[0]
            height = unpack(">L", chunkData[4:8])[0]

        # Parsing the image chunk
        if chunkType == b"IDAT":
            try:
                pdb.set_trace()
                # Uncompressing the image chunk
                bufSize = width * height * 4 + height

                chunkData = decompress(chunkData, -8, bufSize)

            except Exception as e:
                print("Already normalized")
                print(e)
                # The PNG image is normalized
                return None

            # Swapping red & blue bytes for each pixel
            newdata = b""
            for y in range(height):
                i = len(newdata)
                newdata += chunkData[i]
                for x in range(width):
                    i = len(newdata)
                    newdata += chunkData[i+2]
                    newdata += chunkData[i+1]
                    newdata += chunkData[i+0]
                    newdata += chunkData[i+3]

            # Compressing the image chunk
            chunkData = newdata
            chunkData = compress( chunkData )
            chunkLength = len( chunkData )
            chunkCRC = crc32(chunkType)
            chunkCRC = crc32(chunkData, chunkCRC)
            chunkCRC = (chunkCRC + 0x100000000) % 0x100000000

        # Removing CgBI chunk
        if chunkType != b"CgBI":
            newPNG += pack(">L", chunkLength)
            newPNG += chunkType
            if chunkLength > 0:
                newPNG += chunkData
            newPNG += pack(">L", chunkCRC)

        # Stopping the PNG file parsing
        if chunkType == b"IEND":
            break

    return newPNG


def updatePNG(filename):
    data = getNormalizedPNG(filename)

    if data != None:
        file = open(filename, "wb")
        file.write(data)
        file.close()
        return True
    return data
```

Any clue will be appreciated.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Does the v.2 script work on your image? If not, that is the problem. (And I am betting that your image contains multiple IDAT chunks, which this script cannot handle.)

Comment: I'm wondering too, as the error message does not obviously point to a 2.x/3.x converion problem. Maybe you broke something when converting? The original code could help. The Python code looks basically ok, but I don't know the PNG format to check the logic.

Comment: @usr2564301 yes, the script works fine (the one that hasn't been migrated to 3.x) and it transforms my image correctly.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut here is the original code working fine for python 2.x: https://gist.github.com/akfreas/3999195. I'll update the OP with this link

Comment: Got a link to the original script? And an image for which yours fails?

Comment: @usr2564301 Awesome!! Gonna try it asap. Thanks a lot for the solution! :)
Btw, could you please remove the image from the solution please? As it's not mine and I would like to keep it private :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code does not process multiple `IDAT` chunks right away; it does the right thing™ and only concatenates them into a single large object before decompressing it as a whole. `IDAT` chunks are not separately compressed, but your code assumes they do – and so it fails when there is more than one.

> There may be multiple IDAT chunks; if so, they shall appear consecutively with no other intervening chunks. The compressed datastream is then the concatenation of the contents of the data fields of all the IDAT chunks.
>   [11.2.4 IDAT Image data](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11IDAT)

Re-wiring your loop to first gather all `IDAT`s fixes things. Only when an `IEND` chunk is found, this data is decompressed, bytes are swapped, and a new `IDAT` chunk gets created. The final step, appending an `IEND`, closes the file.

```
from struct import *
from zlib import *
import stat
import sys
import os
import zlib

def getNormalizedPNG(filename):
    pngheader = b"\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n"

    file = open(filename, "rb")
    oldPNG = file.read()
    file.close()

    if oldPNG[:8] != pngheader:
        return None

    newPNG = oldPNG[:8]

    chunkPos = len(newPNG)
    chunkD = bytearray()

    foundCGBi = False

    # For each chunk in the PNG file
    while chunkPos < len(oldPNG):

        # Reading chunk
        chunkLength = oldPNG[chunkPos:chunkPos+4]
        chunkLength = unpack(">L", chunkLength)[0]
        chunkType = oldPNG[chunkPos+4 : chunkPos+8]
        chunkData = oldPNG[chunkPos+8:chunkPos+8+chunkLength]
        chunkCRC = oldPNG[chunkPos+chunkLength+8:chunkPos+chunkLength+12]
        chunkCRC = unpack(">L", chunkCRC)[0]
        chunkPos += chunkLength + 12

        # Parsing the header chunk
        if chunkType == b"IHDR":
            width = unpack(">L", chunkData[0:4])[0]
            height = unpack(">L", chunkData[4:8])[0]

        # Parsing the image chunk
        if chunkType == b"IDAT":
            # Concatename all image data chunks
            chunkD += chunkData
            continue

        # Stopping the PNG file parsing
        if chunkType == b"IEND":
            if not foundCGBi:
                print ('Already normalized')
                return None

            bufSize = width * height * 4 + height
            chunkData = decompress(chunkD, -8, bufSize)

            # Swapping red & blue bytes for each pixel
            chunkData = bytearray(chunkData)
            offset = 1
            for y in range(height):
                for x in range(width):
                    chunkData[offset+4*x],chunkData[offset+4*x+2] = chunkData[offset+4*x+2],chunkData[offset+4*x]
                offset += 1+4*width

            # Compressing the image chunk
            #chunkData = newdata
            chunkData = compress( chunkData )
            chunkLength = len( chunkData )
            chunkCRC = crc32(b'IDAT')
            chunkCRC = crc32(chunkData, chunkCRC)
            chunkCRC = (chunkCRC + 0x100000000) % 0x100000000

            newPNG += pack(">L", chunkLength)
            newPNG += b'IDAT'
            newPNG += chunkData
            newPNG += pack(">L", chunkCRC)

            chunkCRC = crc32(chunkType)
            newPNG += pack(">L", 0)
            newPNG += b'IEND'
            newPNG += pack(">L", chunkCRC)
            break

        # Removing CgBI chunk
        if chunkType == b"CgBI":
            foundCGBi = True
        else:
            newPNG += pack(">L", chunkLength)
            newPNG += chunkType
            if chunkLength > 0:
                newPNG += chunkData
            newPNG += pack(">L", chunkCRC)

    return newPNG


def updatePNG(filename):
    data = getNormalizedPNG(filename)

    if data != None:
        file = open(filename+'_fixed.png', "wb")
        file.write(data)
        file.close()
        return True
    return data

updatePNG("broken_image.png")
```

which results in a valid fixed file.

This code does *not* restore the broken `CgBI` alpha channel! If you need proper alpha transparency, you need to apply the row filters to get straight-up RGB values, invert the alpha, and then apply the inverse of the row filters before compressing again.

You could use the [Python wrapper for PNGDefry](https://pypi.org/project/pngdefry), which is a C program that indeed performs these missing steps.

<sup>Disclaimer: I am the writer of PNGdefry.</sup>